# Using read.ssd to convert SAS data set into an R data.frame

Tags: r, sas

I wish to read data into R from SAS data sets in Windows. The read.ssd function allows me to do so, however, it seems to have an issue when I try to import a SAS data set that has any non-alphabetic symbols in its name. For example, I can import `table.sas7bdat` using the following:

```
directory <- "C:/sas data sets"
sashome <- "/Program Files/SAS/SAS 9.1"
table.df <- read.ssd(directory, "table", sascmd = file.path(sashome, "sas.exe"))
```

but I can't do the same for a table SAS data set named `table1.sas7bdat`. It returns an error:

```
Error in file.symlink(oldPath, linkPath) : 
symbolic links are not supported on this version of Windows
```

Given that I do not have the option to rename these data sets, is there a way to read a SAS data set that has non-alphabetic symbols in its name in to R?

Comment: Have you checked if the file `table1.sas7bat` is not a symbolic link?

Comment: Double check that you have the extension right.  SAS datasets are normally .sas7bdat not .sas7bat.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra - I do not believe that it is a symbolic link. I used a SAS data step to create "table1" from "table":<br> `libname dir "C:/sas data sets";`<br> `data dir.table1;`<br> `set dir.table;`<br> `run;`<br> As such, the only difference is that the second data set has a non-alphabetic character in its name. I assume that this must be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Hmm, clearly that is not how I am meant to write code in a comment...

Comment: @Joe, my file extensions are definitely .sas7bdat. I shall edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking about, it looks like others have your problem as well.  Perhaps it's just a bug.

Anyway, try the suggestion from this (old) R help post, posted by the venerable Dan Nordlund who's pretty good at this stuff - and also active on SASL (sasl@listserv.uga.edu) if you want to try cross-posting your question there.
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-December/181616.html

Also, you might consider the transport method if you don't mind 8 character long variable names.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Unfortunately I cannot open that link - is it for a secure network?

Comment: Nope.  I do see a bit of a warning that the HTTPS might not be behaving itself - in chrome it's red, which is not normal.  Try this - https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-December/181616.html

Comment: Cheers, I think I'll just use `sas.get`. By the way, the `sas.get` function has been fixed for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`directory <- "C:/sas data sets"`
`sashome <- "/Program Files/SAS/SAS 9.1"`
`table.df <- read.ssd(library=directory, mem="table1", formats=F,`
`sasprog=file.path(sashome, "sas.exe"))`